# Why is this function returns an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I just don't understand why does this function return an empty array instead of newArr = [1, 2, 3, etc.] depending on the length of the array.

```
function randomFunction(num) {
      var newArr = [];


      for(var i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {   
          newArr.push(i);
     }

      return newArr;
 };
```

Comment: How you are calling this function ?

Comment: randomFunction(8) ;
for example

Comment: numbers doesn't have length method. if argument is number, use, `i<num` instead `num.length`

Comment: `i < num` thats what you want to loop over

Comment: @klarate Then you are doing it wrong. Look at my answer.

Comment: Oh my God...been sitting on this for more than an hour now....Thanks guys, you saved my day!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `num` is supposed to be the length of the new array, and the last number of the range of values, you have to use it directly, instead of using `length` (which is meant to be used for an array):

```js
function randomFunction(num) {
     var newArr = [];

     for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {   
        newArr.push(i);
     }

     return newArr;
 };

 var array = randomFunction(5);
 console.log(array);
```

Also, you might want use `<=` instead of `<`, in case you want to start the value by 1 and go through `n`, and not `n - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function randomFunction(num) {
      var newArr = [];


      for(var i = 1; i < num /* number has no length */; i++) {   
          newArr.push(i);
     }

      return newArr;
 };
```

Es6 alternative for fun:

```
return new Array(num).fill().map((r, i) => i)
```

Answer (score 1):

> randomFunction(8) ; for example

A number doesn't have length at all.  It's already a value.

You do not need length attribute at all. just

```
 for(var i = 1; i < num; i++) {   
        newArr.push(i);
    }
```

---

```js
function randomFunction(num) {
    var newArr = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        newArr.push(i);
    }

    return newArr;
};
console.log(randomFunction(8))
```

Answer (score 1):

`num` is already a number. You don't need use `.lenght` property

```
function randomFunction(num) {
      var newArr = [];


      for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {   
          newArr.push(i);
     }

      return newArr;
 };
randomFunction(5); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```